# Cake PHP3 Rest API can't get Authorization header value

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my `cake PHP3` rest API check the request header `Authorization`. But I can't access it 
`$auth = $this->request->header('Authorization');` 
because the `$auth` value is empty.

I'm using apache server and add below to `.htaccess` as the documentation.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

How could I get the header Authorization value. Sample value like below.

`Authorization: Basic YW50b24ubHVuZGJlcmdAY29kZWJ1aWxkZXJzLnNlOkNiMTMxMDI0ISE=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added below line to  `httpd.conf  <VirtualHost>`

`SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1`

then it works.